# Is it possible to lose at Rock Paper Scissors as Wyatt?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I've played through Wyatt's segment of 400 Days twice, without losing a single round of rock paper scissors. No matter what I do or what I say during this section, it seems that this chapter is completely on rails and I have no choice but leave my buddy behind.

Knowing the franchise, this can't be — there has to be more choice in the section than just flattering or disagreeing with a person you're leaving for dead. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to be the one who goes out of the car?

Comment: Funny, this is my first time playing it and I lost the round.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I managed to lose the game after trying several times was to pick Rock the same option multiple times. The first time you pick rock, he'll play scissors; the second time you play rock, he'll play paper, mentioning how you play rock all the time. The third time you play rock, you'll lose again ("Always with the rock! Too much rock, Wyatt!") and that gives you an alternative path in the section.

This, however, is aggravatingly not *guaranteed* to work. Do the same thing another time, and you might win. This, however, is the only way I've found so far to actually lose.

Comment: For me this was completely random.  I lost 5 times (matches) in a row, and I wanted the achievement for winning it.  Man that took a while because of the time it takes to get there...

Comment: After trying to lose RPS over 15 times, I finally gave up.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to lose at rock paper scissors. In fact, the first time I tried, I lost. You could suggest that you be the one who goes out of the car, but you will most likely still play rock paper scissors. The way I found to work is if you answer the questions in a certain way you can be the one that gets out. If you respond to everything with the response that suggests you go or he doesn't, he will let you go.

Answer (score -3):

There is a way to lose. You just have to keep trying to lose. The computer pulls up a pretty strong AI (related to it losing), although I'm pretty sure that if you get lucky you can lose in the game.

Comment: The problem is that the two closest checkpoints around this moment are either five minutes before (when the driver turns the lights off) or one second after the winner is decided. If you blink and allow the autosave to happen, you have to redo the whole segment again from the very start.